# Chrome Only - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: jquery

I have found and tried all other responses to this from other answers and nothing has worked as they are not 100% exactly my situation.

I have FarmA and FarmB on the *same* domain
I have a Site on FarmB that is opened to everyone as a Contributor
I have a form on FarmA that is using jQuery (below) to write data to the list on FarmB

*This works fine in IE8+* and fails every time in Chrome with the SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. I can run the same call via Postman in Chrome and it works/returns. Running Fiddler during my test shows two responses for the single call, one a 401 and one a 200 with the data I want, however the below code errors every time.

Any thoughts/ideas?

```
var serviceURL = url + "/_api/contextinfo"

    $.ajax({
        url: serviceURL,
        async: true, //I've tried false :( and removing this completely with no change
        type: 'POST',
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, //I've removed this as a test with no change
        contentType: "text/plain", //I've tried this set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded with no change
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            formDig = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            ajaxFailure(data); //In Chrome only hits this every time
        }
    });
```

UPDATE: Found the root error from Chrome to be:
Failed to load https://FarmB/sites/FarmB/_api/contextinfo: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://FarmA' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I also went to and tried an overly simplistic

```
$.post(serviceURL, function (data) {
     setFormDigest(data);
  }); //DOESN'T WORK IN IE
```

and got the exact same error. Why if it works on the same computer just fine in IE?

Comment: Did you try to change your contentType to "application/json;odata=verbose"

Comment: Thank you Marco, yep, tried that with no change; same error